# Use Gmail / Third-Party Credentials to login to my application

Tags: authentication

I am gonna develop a voting system and I don't want to create a unique DB and a login page.. i am expecting users to login in through Gmail / Other sites namely Company site.. to see the voting pages.. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure you don't want to keep absolutely no information whatsoever from your users...? Like what they voted for?

Comment: Dig into a given provider's API. OpenID and OAuth are two protocols often used for authentication (even though the latter was designed for authorisation)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the google API to your purpose, to learn more about it you can read here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/
Another major site is Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) standard protocol, used by Google, Facebook, etc...

Comment: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) here you can find a sample and detailed info

Answer (score 0):

yes, that s the purpose of [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) and [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID). Many apps supports this.

Based on your language, you can find OAuth Providers and APIs